# Calculating motor movements without conditionals

Tags: math

I have a stepper motor that I am trying to move to a desired position. For simplicities sake, lets say that my motor takes 100 steps to complete a full rotation around. and that the motor shaft can only move in one direction. Is there an equation that takes in two numerical inputs, a desired position (expressed by positive integers 1-100) and the current position (expressed by a positive integer 1-100) and returns the amount the motor needs to move forward.

For example

CurrentPos 90 DesPos 60 Output 70

CurrentPos 20 DesPos 60 Output 40

CurrentPos 60 DesPos 60 Output 0

Answer (score 0):

The answer has just occurred to me the equation (100+(desPos-CurrentPos))%100 will give the correct answer